# Could not get datagrid postback values on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

This ASP.Net C# Web application project is developed in 2007.
In this project, there are lots of customizations/extensions to the regular way of doing things.
Examples are - the project has a **PageBase** class extending **System.Web.UI.Page**, and similarly has **DataGridBase** class extending **System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid,IControl**, and so on.
Pretty much all the controls I develop should extend the related ones as it fits.

I never learned or worked with .Net. Lately, I am put in the development of this old project.

My question could be related to basics as well.
My situation is an aspx page, a datagrid control (taking data from a datatable through databinding), and a button.
This datagrid has custom bound columns, etc. I am able to databind a datatable to this grid, and get the values displayed in the page. The datagrid has rows where user can enter text, choose a dropdown, etc.
I also have a button on the page.

On the button click, I would like to read the post(back) values and validate.
If there is any input error, I would like to go back to the page with error message(s)
If everything is good, I can persist them in the database. I have the database query end all written already.

During postback of the button click, in the debug, I also see the control landing into the initialize of the datagrid, etc. If it is appropriate, I could do the validation (and persistence) of the user entry here as well.

**How would I go about reading the post data in the button onclick.**
Though, I can see the postcollection values, and I do not think it is correct to interpret the datagrid values this way.
I guess there is a better way to get the postback values (related to the datagrid).
**Is there a way (through viewstate or any other means) to (automatically) get the user entry (postback) into the datagrid or to the datatable from which the grid is originally bound?**
Hopefully, I am making sense in my question.
I could not find a similar situation (example) in this project code. So far, all the data entries are to individual (text box, checkbox, etc.) controls on the page (not associated to the datagrid with a worksheet kind of data entry)

If I print the postback values, I get to see them

```
 public class AddSHEButton : ButtonBase, IPostBackDataHandler
{
    bool IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = postCollection.AllKeys.SelectMany(postCollection.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v });
            foreach (var item in items)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.key, item.value);
```

Here is the console out of the postback values...

```
__VIEWSTATE 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
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl02$textbox: 2
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl02$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl02$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl03$textbox: 1
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl03$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl03$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl04$textbox: 2
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl04$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl04$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl05$textbox: 
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl05$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl05$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl06$textbox: 
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl06$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl06$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl07$textbox: 
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl07$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl07$ctl01 2021
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl08$textbox: 
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl08$ctl00 01
SuperHoursEntryGrid$ctl08$ctl01 2021
button_add Add
```

[image: Screenshot of the datagrid on the page]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well of course you would no more try to parse out and “analyse” the post back information then say would you dump a rich environment and say try to hand code things in assembler.

You don’t show how you filled the grid view in the first place.

However, usually you create or fill out a data table, and then execute a data bind of the table to the grid.

At that point, the grid will persist round trips (post backs). But the data table of the grid WILL NOT.

I would only persist the data table used for the grid source IF you want to send all grid edits back to the database in one shot.

In a lot of cases, you only need to say click on some button on a row, and say jump to a page (or display) some type of form to edit or display that one row.

In your screen cap, you have a add button, but you don’t show if you have say a save button, or what you want to occur?

In other words, do you want to say verify the data with some “save” button, or some other action?

I ask, since what you eventually want to do will thus quite much result in what road you need or want to take here.

However in ALL cases you certainly don’t have to worry about or attempt to look at post back data.

You use the built in methods and properties of that control, and they are VERY rich, and can handle 99% of what you final goals are.

And it not clear if “add” button is to add one row, or “add” means save all the data?

It also not clear if you using data bound fields, or each grid row has standard asp.net text boxes, labels etc? (As templated controls).

If a data table was created (say from a sql query) and bound into the grid?

Well, then you could have say a button on each row or in your case some “save” button, and perhaps you “add” button (as noted it not clear if your add button is to add one row or do some kind of overall save of the whole grid.

But, to iterate the rows in the grid? (and without having persisted the data table? (which you have to save – either view state or session).

Our markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="26px" Text="Button" Width="150px" />
<br />
```

Our code to load up the grid:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName,City FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

            Dim rData As New DataTable
            rData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            GridView1.DataSource = rData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```

Or as C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack == false)
   {
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName,City FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3)))
       {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

        DataTable rData = new DataTable();
        rData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

        GridView1.DataSource = rData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
       } 
   }
}
```

So above gives this:

[image]

As you can see - VERY little markup, and VERY little code so far.

Now, our button code when clicked will "tarverse" each row.

The code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each dvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim s = ""
        For Each MyCell As TableCell In dvRow.Cells
            If s <> "" Then s &= ","
            s &= MyCell.Text
        Next
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next

End Sub
```

or as C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (GridViewRow dvRow in GridView1.Rows)
   {
    var s = "";
    foreach (TableCell MyCell in dvRow.Cells)
       {
           if (s != "")
               s += ",";
           s += MyCell.Text;
       }
       Debug.Print(s);
   }
}
```

OutPut:

```
78,Darcy,Caroll,Kelowna
99,Don,Grant,Kimberley
73,Karen,Tocher,Golden
81,Stewart,Winterburn,Edmonton
100,Heather,Carrier,Kimberley
72,Reservations,&nbsp;,Calgary
153,Upper Springs,&nbsp;,Fernie
95,Erin,Kavanagh,Invermere
144,&nbsp;,&nbsp;,Banff
102,Jim,Lloyd,Golden
```

Now, I shared above, since I wanted to point out that I can't recall trying to parse post back data - you have a rich object model, and thus you get/grab/use/process the data that way.

Now in above, I used "cells", since of course I do NOT have any templated markup and standard controls that I created in code (I just have above code - so each column is a cell as my loop collection of rows shows.

So, it not clear when/where/what button you have that you want to run or have some verification, and it not clear if you using templated controls for the grid, and are using the Edit template, or you just rolling your own (either way is ok).

So, your add button code can loop/check, but I would assume some kind of edit button on each row? Or perhaps you want user edits and then a save of all data back to the database.

Regardless of above?
No, you don't try and process some postback data - you have a rather rich object model, and quite a few more events that can deal with the data.

Comment: That's Visual Basic.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Add button is the Save all things. So validation of all values will happen at the button click. I am trying your recommendation, and will update shortly

Comment: Ah, ok - that button is to save all. If that is the case, then I would VERY much persist a data table here. That way you can write back the whole table in one shot with the 'add/save' button. I'll post some more comments as to how the save could look later today.

Comment: On your buttonclick method, you have GridView1.Rows. How did you get this GridView1 object?

Comment: Gridview1 is the ID/name of control I dropped onto the web form. Look at the first part - note the GridView1 in the asp web markup I provided. That markup is the FULL markup I had. And then i shoved that data table into the grid view, and then the screen cap shows the results. So its like TextBox1, or dropList1, or in this case? GridView1. You noted "data grid", but assuming this is web based, then the two controls tend to be either GridView, or ListView.  You used the term a grid of data, or perhaps you REALLY do mean datagrid - but that NOT asp.net (web based) controls - HUGE difference then

Comment: Mine is a web application. It is DataGrid control. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8
Your example is (GridView)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8
There must be some differences. 
The more I look online, I am tending to think that DataGrid does not directly support full editing, rather with an Edit Command column (with Edit, Update and Cancel buttons alternating). Due to custom base classes (for page, controls) doing much work, it is challenging.

Comment: Should I use GridView instead?

Comment: You can still use datagrid (it just quite a bit older). I tend to like gridview, since then gridview, listview, data repeater, form view, details view ALL work quite much the same. So once you learn one and get all this working, then you learned about 4+ more controls that you can see/use/ the same way.

Comment: Due to time constraints, I took non-grid approach for adding data. Since we do not allow edits, and this is only to add entries, user experience isn't that much compromised. Since our project have more work lined up, soon I would try the DataGrid itself to work as an editable worksheet, and/or use GridView control. As designed, our project has YYYBase classes pretty much for all the controls (Label, Button, DataGrid, Repeater, etc.) extending ASP.NET control classes, and have custom work to get the controls to life. So I need to do more than just using a new control. I will update soon.